# jquery makes anything under it disapear

Tags: jquery

When I add this block of code anywhere in my appkication anything under it dissapears.

Is there an error I am not seeing?

```
  var ads = $('.ads').offset().top;
     $(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(this).scrollTop() > ads) {
       $('.ads').addClass('fixed');
        console.log('toptoptopt');
      }
      else {
       $('.ads').removeClass('fixed');
       console.log('no top');
      }
   });
    });(jQuery);
```

And this is how im calling the `div ads`

```
{if $banners.3}
<div class="ads">
    <div class="banner-side">{banner area="3"}</div>    
</div>
    {/if}
```

This is done with smarty php. A terrible thing no one should use.

Here is some more JS i used and the same problem exist. Could something in my site be conflicting with this code?

```
(function($){
$('#ads').addClass('disable');      


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
           var st = $(this).scrollTop();
           st > 250 ? $('#ads').addClass('fixed').removeClass('disable') : $('#ads').addClass('disable').removeClass('fixed');
         });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you provide more code of the class .ads where does it exist in the body and etc...

Comment: are you sure it should be `});(jQuery);` and not `})(jQuery);`?

Comment: the class ads is a css class making the position: fixed to the right side of the page. its in the body yes. but i put the ads on one page. and add the jquery to the footer and the footer on all pages it gone.. then the header and now the whole page is gone on all pages.

Comment: i added the div where im calling ads. lol why would this question get down voted?

Comment: "Anything under *it* disappears" - What is "*it*"?

Comment: The block of jquery i posted in my question. Anywhere I put the block of code everything underneath it disappears. if i put it under body tag whole page is gone or right above footer then the footer is gone.

Comment: Okay, so "it" is the piece of code, and "under" means whatever code or markup is under that piece of code. It sounds like it's failing to render everything else in the response once it hits that piece of code. Have you checked the developer console to see if there are any errors? You can try googling how to bring the console up depending on what browser you're using.

Answer (score -1):

The Javascript interpreter stops processing a script when it hits a syntax error.  Anything after the error will be ignored.

In this case, it is probably the `});(jQuery);`.  Either because of the unbalanced braces, or because of the stray semicolon - as attila pointed out.

**Update**

Your Javascript syntax is wrong.  In your first block of code, you are missing the opening brace/bracket pair that matches the last line.  What it probably should be is:

```
(function($){
   var ads = $('.ads').offset().top;
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() > ads) {
         $('.ads').addClass('fixed');
         console.log('toptoptopt');
      } else {
         $('.ads').removeClass('fixed');
         console.log('no top');
      }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Your second one is also wrong.

```
(function($){

   $('#ads').addClass('disable');      

   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (st > 250) {
         $('#ads').addClass('fixed').removeClass('disable');
      } else {
         $('#ads').addClass('disable').removeClass('fixed');
      }
   });

})(jQuery);
```

You can't just copy and paste bits of code and fumble through it.  You need to know what you are doing.  May I suggest you take some online classes on Javascript?

Comment: I changes it to       })(jQuery); and still anything below it does not get loaded to the page.

Comment: Where is the matching opening brace/bracket pair for `})(jQuery);`?  At the moment they are unbalanced.

Comment: I am not sure. I am not pro with JS. Could you look at the code block and if you see something that needs to be added or changed correct it and post it as answer? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @NichoDiaz: What does the developer console say?